# ActiveRecord connection dying on random Ruby methods (.size, .each)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using ActiveRecord version 3.2.14 (and tried 3.2.15 rc as well) with TinyTDS + activerecord sql adapter to connect to my SQL Server database.

I'm running into extremely weird behavior where this exception is thrown:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record
/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection':
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)
```

but according to the trace:

```
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:229:in `columns'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:249:in `column_names'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:262:in `column_methods_hash'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:74:in `all_attributes_exists?'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:27:in `method_missing'
from /usr/local/debugging-exchange-test/app/controllers/new_orders_controller.rb:15:in `block in start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:6:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:6:in `each'
from /usr/local/debugging-exchange-test/app/controllers/new_orders_controller.rb:13:in `start'
from /usr/local/debugging-exchange-test/lib/exchange.rb:57:in `testing'
from /usr/local/debugging-exchange-test/lib/exchange.rb:39:in `initialize'
from /usr/local/debugging-exchange-test/lib/exchange.rb:104:in `new'
from /usr/local/debugging-exchange-test/lib/exchange.rb:104:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:203:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:203:in `start_load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:298:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/controller.rb:70:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons.rb:147:in `block in run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in `call'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in `catch_exceptions'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons.rb:146:in `run'
from ./data_exchange:15:in `<main>'
```

it's happening here on the `each` method:

```
def start
  web_queue = Nti::Order.where("orderid IS NOT NULL AND updated_by_exchange_at IS NULL AND orderstatus <> 9")
  logger.info "web_queue size: #{web_queue.length}"
  web_queue.each do |nti_order| #<---- this line
    # logger.info nti_order.orderid
    web_order = Web::Order.find_by_id(nti_order.orderid)
    raise "Couldn't find web order with ID #{nti_order.orderid}" if web_order.nil?
    web_order.status = 99
    web_order.save!
    logger.info "Web order with ID #{web_order.id} updated to status = 99"
  end
end
```

And before this happened, I was getting the same exact error but for this line because of the `.size` method:

`logger.info "web_queue size: #{web_queue.size}"`

When I changed it to `.length` it works. What the heck is going on? These methods have nothing to do with ActiveRecord. My Array methods are throwing ActiveRecord exceptions.

BTW this is a ruby app (not rails) that uses activerecord to exchange data between two databases.

And just to show that the database connection works, when I change the method to do this:

```
def start
  a = Nti::Order.where("orderid IS NOT NULL AND updated_by_exchange_at IS NULL AND orderstatus <> 9")
  logger.info a.first.inspect
  logger.info "done"
end
```

it works. This works as well:

```
def start
  a = Nti::Order.where("orderid IS NOT NULL AND updated_by_exchange_at IS NULL AND orderstatus <> 9")
  # logger.info a.size
  puts a.map{ |order| order.orderid }

  logger.info "done"
end
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: They *do* have something to do with AR, in that the query won't happen until after you actually need data. From the docs: "If the collection has been already loaded length and size are equivalent. If not and you are going to need the records anyway this method will take one less query. Otherwise size is more efficient."

Comment: I updated the question to show an example of it working

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the poolsize in database.yml. 
Change the default `pool: 5` to something large.